# Business Workflow Process Management

Tags: content-management-system, workflow, orchardcms

I want to create a Business Workflow Management System for managing issues.
The system should allow managers to define ***workflows***. A ***workflow*** consists of multiple departments linked in **order**.
Then an issue can be opened, the issue has a workflow assigned so basically when a department reviews the issue and closes it with certain remarks (or uploads a file) the issue is moved to the next department for review.

My question is if Orchard CMS is suitable for something like this or if there are any open source projects that can be adapted to something like this?
Other alternatives i found would be sensenet or jBPM 6.

I am limited to using oracle database and i would like to use an open source framework in .NET or JAVA. I have experience with Orchard CMS but i am not sure it is the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Orchard you can achieve required functionality through Workflow module.
The simplest way, as I see it, would be:

1. Create Content type for your issues.
2. Create custom form that gives you edit and browse funcionalities (can be done other ways too, but I have found custom forms suitable for this kind of things.)
3. Extend User profile with Department info (add Department to the Profile part).
4. Set permissions to the form (these are enough fine grained).
5. Create workflow (react on a event, then do something - for example, if Dep. A has set status to "MyFineDraft" then assign the issue to the Dep. B, etc.)

This is some basic approach. There are other ways to get what's asked, but this should give you an overall idea. Everything described here can be done without coding. Sure, you can code it too.